# Splice array not removing correct position and overlapping the same one (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm adding to my array clicked input checkbox and then I replace the strings and push to another array. If I click User 1 and then User 2, but then I uncheck the User 1, it removes User 2 from array instead of user one.

Here's my code sand box with a part of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-shape-cfu1n

Also sometimes it doesn't remove array position and overlapps the same user.

Any ideas?

```
<form id="formCriaJogo" method="post" action="./components/insert.php">
  <label>Other users</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="autor"
    id="autor"
    placeholder="Escreve o nome do autor"
  />

  <div id="autorLista" style="display: block;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="opcaoAutor" value="1,User 1" />
    <label for="1">User 1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="opcaoAutor" value="2,User 2" />
    <label for="2">User 2</label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>

<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#autor").keyup(function() {
  var query = $(this).val();

  if (query != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "./search.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("input#autor").css("margin-bottom", "0");
        $("#autorLista").css("display", "block");
        $("#autorLista").fadeIn();
        $("#autorLista").html(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
});

var index = [];
var users = [];

//alteração do check box
$("#formCriaJogo").delegate("input[name=opcaoAutor]", "change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#selecionados").css("display", "block");
    index.push($(this).val());
    //console.log('guardou -> ' + index);

    $("p#selecionados").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
      var a = index[i].toString().split(",");

      var user = {
        user_id: a[0],
        nome_user: a[1]
      };
      $("p#selecionados").append(user.nome_user);
    }

    users.push(user);
    console.log(users);
  } else {
    //if uncheck remove the element from array
    if ((index1 = index.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1)) {
      index.splice($.inArray(index1, index), 1);
      users.splice($.inArray(index1, index), 1);
      console.log("removed");

      $("p#selecionados").html("");
      for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
        var a = index[i].toString().split(",");

        var user = {
          user_id: a[0],
          nome_user: a[1]
        };
        $("p#selecionados").append(user.nome_user);
      }
    }
    console.log(users);
  }
});
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear just change code in your `else` portion like I have done for you, it may help you thanks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var index = [];
var users = [];

//alteração do check box
$("#formCriaJogo").delegate("input[name=opcaoAutor]", "change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#selecionados").css("display", "block");
    index.push($(this).val());
    //console.log('guardou -> ' + index);

    $("p#selecionados").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
      var a = index[i].toString().split(",");

      var user = {
        user_id: a[0],
        nome_user: a[1]
      };
      $("p#selecionados").append(user.nome_user);
    }

    users.push(user);
    // console.log(users);
  } else {
    //if uncheck remove the element from array
    var index1 = index.indexOf($(this).val());
    if (index1 > -1) {
      index.splice(index1, 1);
      users.splice(index1, 1);
      console.log("removed");

      $("p#selecionados").html("");
      for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
        var a = index[i].toString().split(",");

        var user = {
          user_id: a[0],
          nome_user: a[1]
        };
        $("p#selecionados").append(user.nome_user);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(users);
});
});
```